# Draggable <td> content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, html-table

I would like to use jQuery and its drag-and-drop function, such as:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

In my case, I would like to enable drag-and-droping on `<td>` content of an HTML table.  For instance with a table of 20x20, in order to move a `<img />` tag from a cell to an other cell.

Is that hard to do? I don't see any example after searches.  If you're got one or if you can show me how to process, I will be cool!

Comment: Have you tried implementing the examples from the link you posted? It's right on there! Give it a shot before posting here, man! Maybe you didn't see this part, the [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: Sorry Jason, but it's not as simple as you could think.  jQuery drag-and-drop don't really work for table content.  Even if it's possible to drag-and-drop TD content from a cell to an other cell, this moved content is not center in its new cell.  And after some tests it's seems to be much harder then you said.  But it's fun (and it's not a homework ;)

Comment: have you tried putting your `<td>` content into a div? not get rid of your table, but do `<td><div class="myContent">Content</div></td>` and use the `<div>` s as your draggables?

Comment: Yes (div, span, ...) but it steal not work, and I think I will begin to search an other solution in order to finish my project.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: It should work if you do it right. It doesn't care what container you put it in. Your selectors are probably incorrect...

Answer (score 2):

Try using `jQuery.ui.sortable`.  That should allow for drag and drop within the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a div inside the .so that yo can drag the div and drop it where you want.